# View Not Updating After click event from Popup

Tags: angularjs

Confused why is the textbox value not changing to "bbb" after click of the button on the popup.

The jsfiddle is attached.

UI:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="test_value"/>
    <button ng-click="clickToOpen()">My Modal</button>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="templateId">

        <div id="target" ng-click="test1()" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
          <input type="button" ng-click="test()" value="Set Data" />
        </div>
    </script>
```

Controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngDialog']);

function MyCtrl($scope, ngDialog) {
    $scope.test_value = 'aaa';
    $scope.clickToOpen = function () {
     $scope.dialog = ngDialog.open({ template: 'templateId' , scope : $scope});
    };

    $scope.test1 = function()
    {
    $scope.test_value = 'bbb';
    console.log($scope.test_value);
    $scope.dialog.close();
    };
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mb6o4yd1/590/

Comment: Because the button `ngClick` has specified `test` as the function to call on the button click and not `test1`.  The `div` `ngClick` will not be called because the click event will not propagate from the button up to the div unless you write a custom event handler.

Comment: my bad. please see new fiddle..i have tagged correct events but still no luck..http://jsfiddle.net/mb6o4yd1/594/

Comment: answer updated with new fiddle.

Comment: pls suggest why this is not working ...http://jsfiddle.net/vuvxphv3/2/

Comment: if i remove ng-controller="MyCtrl" it is working but with the ng-controller="MyCtrl" it is not working...just curious..

Comment: The second `MyCtrl` creates a second controller with a separate scope that is different from the outer `MyCtrl`.  It doesn’t reference the same initially created controller.  Please accept whichever of the answers if it (which it seems it has) helped you figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line

```
        <div id="target" ng-click="test1()" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
          <input type="button" ng-click="test()" value="Set Data" />
        </div>
```

to

```
        <div id="target">
          <input type="button" ng-click="test1()" value="Set Data" />
        </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vuvxphv3/1/